# How to use IFileOpenDialog in powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I need to custom an OpenFileDialog and remove left panel.

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    Multiselect = $true
    Filter = 'Documents (*.docx)|*.docx|SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx' # 'All Files (*.*)|*.*'
    Title = $Title
}

[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FileBrowser.FileNames
```

but is not possible with [`OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

that seems possible with the [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(v=VS.85).aspx) (he has [`_FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457282(v=vs.85).aspx)), but I can not use it in powershell